# GCG in ScipOptSuite-7.0.2: Linux self-extracting archive installation lets me start SCIP, but not GCG

Tags: linux, scip

I installed the latest ScipOptSuite (7.0.2) using the self-extracting archive (yes, after installing the required packages gcc g++ gfortran liblapack3 libtbb2 libcliquer1 libopenblas-dev libgsl23 as demanded at the SCIP download site) and if I navigate into the newly created directory (i.e., `/home/stefan/SCIPOptSuite-7.0.2`), I can start SCIP via `./bin/SCIP`:

```
SCIP version 7.0.2 [precision: 8 byte] [memory: block] [mode: optimized] [LP solver: SoPlex 5.0.2] [GitHash: e9d280a398]
Copyright (C) 2002-2020 Konrad-Zuse-Zentrum fuer Informationstechnik Berlin (ZIB)

External codes: 
  SoPlex 5.0.2         Linear Programming Solver developed at Zuse Institute Berlin (soplex.zib.de) [GitHash: e24c304e]
  CppAD 20180000.0     Algorithmic Differentiation of C++ algorithms developed by B. Bell (www.coin-or.org/CppAD)
  ZLIB 1.2.11          General purpose compression library by J. Gailly and M. Adler (zlib.net)
  GMP 6.2.1            GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library developed by T. Granlund (gmplib.org)
  ZIMPL 3.4.0          Zuse Institute Mathematical Programming Language developed by T. Koch (zimpl.zib.de)
  PaPILO 1.0.2         parallel presolve for integer and linear optimization (https://github.com/lgottwald/PaPILO) [GitHash: 62d2842]
  bliss 0.73p          Computing Graph Automorphism Groups by T. Junttila and P. Kaski (http://www.tcs.hut.fi/Software/bliss/)
  Ipopt 3.13.2         Interior Point Optimizer developed by A. Waechter et.al. (www.coin-or.org/Ipopt)

user parameter file <scip.set> not found - using default parameters

SCIP> quit
```

However, when I try to start GCG via `./bin/GCG`, I get the following error:

`./bin/gcg: error while loading shared libraries: libscip.so.7.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

If I navigate into the lib directory to check its content, here is what I get:

```
Stefan@stefan-VirtualBox:~/SCIPOptSuite-7.0.2-Linux/lib$ ls
cmake  libclusol.a  libgcg.so  libgcg.so.3.0  libgcg.so.3.0.4.0  libscip.so  libscip.so.7.0  libscip.so.7.0.2.0  libsoplex.a  libsoplex-pic.a  libzimpl.a  libzimpl-pic.a
stefan@stefan-VirtualBox:~/SCIPOptSuite-7.0.2-Linux/lib$ ls -la
insgesamt 20332
drwxr-xr-x 3 stefan stefan     4096 Dez 19 01:01 .
drwxrwxr-x 5 stefan stefan     4096 Feb 16 14:43 ..
drwxr-xr-x 7 stefan stefan     4096 Dez 19 01:01 cmake
-rw-r--r-- 1 stefan stefan   197786 Dez 19 00:55 libclusol.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 stefan stefan       13 Dez 19 01:01 libgcg.so -> libgcg.so.3.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 stefan stefan       17 Dez 19 01:01 libgcg.so.3.0 -> libgcg.so.3.0.4.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 stefan stefan  2279000 Dez 19 01:00 libgcg.so.3.0.4.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 stefan stefan       14 Dez 19 01:01 libscip.so -> libscip.so.7.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 stefan stefan       18 Dez 19 01:01 libscip.so.7.0 -> libscip.so.7.0.2.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 stefan stefan 14708920 Dez 19 00:59 libscip.so.7.0.2.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 stefan stefan  1115142 Dez 19 00:56 libsoplex.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 stefan stefan  1126422 Dez 19 00:55 libsoplex-pic.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 stefan stefan   681454 Dez 19 00:55 libzimpl.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 stefan stefan   679454 Dez 19 00:55 libzimpl-pic.a
```

I think it should be possible to start GCG from an installation via the self-extracting archive, but I cannot get it to work. It seems to me that there is a reference to the file `libscip.so.7.0.2.0` which does exist, but it does not seem to work. Where is my mistake? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue and this fixed it for me (although my installation version was v7.0.3).

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/SCIPOptSuite-7.0.3-Linux/lib
```

Note this only applies to the terminal instance the line was run in (so once it's closed you have to run the line again in another terminal instance to reapply this change).

Refer to this link for how to permanently set it if you need this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/58814/how-do-i-add-environment-variables